# rewrite rule 'folder' does not work if matches original page name

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am adding some rewrite rules to my htaccess file for news articles and eventdetails so i can embed the title in the url, but when i set the 'folder' name the same as the original page, it does not work.
When the 'folder' name is different, it works fine

working htaccess file is like this...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


# Rewrite for eventdetail.php?EventID=1&EventName=event-name
RewriteRule ^event/([0-9]+)*$ eventdetail.php?EventID=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^event/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)*$ eventdetail.php?EventID=$1&EventName=$2 [NC,L]
```

so, for example, if I use ^event/...

my url is sitename/event/id/eventname and this works ok,

but if I use ^eventdetail/...

my url is sitename/eventdetail/id/eventname and this fails, the get parameter for the event id is not passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rewrite your rule a little differently to handle both rules. Part of the problem is probably multiviews as to why you can't use the filename. Turn that off. Also I would also make trailing slash optional.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite for eventdetail.php?EventID=1&EventName=event-name
RewriteRule ^event/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/?$ eventdetail.php?EventID=$1&EventName=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^event/([0-9]+)/?$ eventdetail.php?EventID=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer if it helped you.